# Show svn revision number own for each netbeans project file

Tags: svn, netbeans

How to show versioning labels for project files (php) in Netbeans, and for each file own last change revision number like in Eclipse?

Now my all project files have same revision number (last revision of project).

```
- project [37]
    file1.php [37]
    file2.php [37]
    file3.php [37]
  - folder1 [37]
      file4.php [37]
```

But in Eclipse each file has own revision like it should i think.

```
- project [37]
    file1.php [23]
    file2.php [37]
    file3.php [12]
  - folder1 [12]
      file4.php [12]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display of the repository version number instead of the file version number (as well as other SVN variables) is the subject of [bug 121755](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=121755) in the [NetBeans Bugzilla](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/).

So the answer to your question is: **you can't** (at this time).